# What is ''A, hoping to B'' in Japanese?

Tags: translation, word-choice, nuances

I'm making Japanese lyrics, and I'm trying to say:

> I try to escape(wake up) from fate

> Hoping to open my eyes

and ended up writing this:

> 運命から逃れ(起き)ようとする

> 目を覚ますように

For 逃れ(起き)よう, I'm doing the thing where you write down the kanji for the meaning you want but with an alternative pronunciation, imagery, and/or double meaning as I've seen in some songs as a stylistic choice. (I hope I did it right.)

As for my actual question, is there a Japanese equivalent expression for ''I'm hoping to...'' or a better way to say it in Japanese? The closest equivalents I've found are ~ように, ~といい(ね/な), and 願う/祈る/望む, but none of these seem right for what I want to express.

〜ように feels like the closest for me so far since it has the meaning of ''in order to'' which is kinda the same meaning as ''hoping to'', but I feel like its nuance isn't the same. Saying AようにB feels like you're **certain** B will cause A to happen, whereas ''I'll do B, hoping A'' in English has **uncertainty** with whether B will actually happen or not even if you do A.

I get how 〜といい(ね/な) can be used as ''I hope __'', but I feel like the usage is wrong for what I'm trying to say. If I used this, it seems like it would sound more like ''I try to escape from fate. It would be nice if I my eyes opened too.'' which isn't what I want to express.

The words 願う, 祈る, and 望む feel like they're too strong for this usage too.

Answer (score 1):

Some other grammar patterns that might give you an idea:

今月末までに完成させる(つもりで)、毎日努力をした

(With the intention of) finishing by the end of the month, I worked on it every day.

新しいハリーポッターの本を(買おうと)、あの本屋へ初めて行きました

I went to that bookstore for the first time (with the intention) of buying the new harry potter book